# Travis CI - knitr and dependencies

Tags: r, travis-ci, r-package

I am using travis for my package for CI. I got an error on mac on R release version an devel version. These are the errors i get:

On release version:

```
Error in loadVignetteBuilder(pkgdir, TRUE) : 
  vignette builder 'knitr' not found
Execution halted
The command "R CMD build  ." failed and exited with 1 during .
Your build has been stopped.
```

On devel version:

```
Installing packages into ‘/Users/travis/R/Library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Error: (converted from warning) unable to access index for repository https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/4.0:
  cannot open URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/4.0/PACKAGES'
Execution halted
The command "Rscript -e 'deps <- remotes::dev_package_deps(dependencies = NA);remotes::install_deps(dependencies = TRUE);if (!all(deps$package %in% installed.packages())) { message("missing: ", paste(setdiff(deps$package, installed.packages()), collapse=", ")); q(status = 1, save = "no")}'" failed and exited with 1 during .
```

Concerning the error on release version, I have specified Suggests: knitr and VignetteBuilder: knitr in DESCRIPTION file.
The error on devel version I do not understand. It seems like an error on TRAVIS.

These are the settings in travis yml file:

```
language: R
sudo: false
cache: packages
warnings_are_errors: true

os:
  - linux
  - osx

r:
  - oldrel
  - release
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have manually added install all dependencies. Then the problem was with devtools not being installed so I added that too.

This was added to the travis yml

```
install:
  - R -e 'install.packages("devtools")'
  - R -e 'devtools::install_deps(dep = T)'
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

R needs `knitr` to be installed to build packages. Maybe this package is missing in your base environment (I am not familiar with travis).

Could you maybe add a step to explicitely install it, such as

```sh
R -e 'install.packages("knitr")'
```

Comment: I have tried that and specified it wrongly. Travis couldn't start... (NOOB). I reverted commit on github and now I do not get error on release version. This seems inconsistent.

I still get an error on devel version though...

To sum up, I changed nothing and one error disappeared... Any thoughts on error on devel version?